# Analyze the integrability of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2 (\ln x)^3}$ in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I have the following function and I have to analyze its integrability in $(0,\infty)$:$\space$

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2 (\ln x)^3}$

---

I'm trying to use this definition:$\space$

f integrable $\leftrightarrow $ $\int_X |f| d\mu$ $\space$

But I don't know what to do... I know that $lnx$ is going tobe negative in $(0,1)$ so I can't say that $f(x)=|f(x)|$... So what do I have to do? I also know that if I think that it is integrable I have to try to bound it with a bigger function. But I have no idea...$\space$

I think that it is finite... but I'm not sure about it... $\space$

Could someone help me to do this exercise?

Comment: The function is integrable on $(\varepsilon,+\infty)$ for any $\varepsilon>1$. It is not integrable on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

The function  is not integrable. It is enough to show that the integral form $1$ to $\infty$is $\infty$. Note that the function is non-negative on this interval. Put $y =\ln x$. The interval $(1, \infty)$ changes to $(0,\infty)$ since $\ln 1=0$ and $\ln x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.  We get $\int_{0} ^{\infty} \frac {e^{-y}} {y^{3}}dy \geq \int_{0} ^{1} \frac {e^{-y}} {y^{3}}dy \geq e^{-1} \int_{0} ^{1} \frac 1 {y^{3}}dy=\infty$

Comment: I don't understand what have you done... Why did you put from $0$ to $1$ if I am analyzing in $(0,\infty)$? An if $y=lnx$, f(x) is going to be $\frac{e^(-2y)}{y^3} $ if I'm not wrong... Can you explain it in another way please?

Comment: If the integral over a subinterval is $\infty$ so is the integral all the way from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. In this case it is enough to consider the integral over $(0,1)$. When you make the change of variable you should rememeber to write $dx$ in terms of $dy$. Here $dx=e^{y}dy$. @User160

Comment: And how have you done the last step?? I mean why is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-y}}{y^3} dy >=e^{-1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{y^3}dy$ ???

Comment: $y<1$ implies $e^{-y} >e^{-1}$. @User160

Comment: So we can say that $f(x)$ is not integrable in $(0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: @User160 Yes, that is what I proved.

Comment: And where you have written the integrals, the integrals don't have to go between absolut value??

Comment: @User160 I have added more details. I hope it is clear to you now.

Comment: Thanks! and sorry but I've got another doubt... I the edit you say that it is enough to se that the integral from 1 to $\infty$ is $\infty$ but then in the prove you have seen that the integral from $0$ to $1$ is $\infty$